# Query database based on drop down menu selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

How can I query my db based on a drop menu selection?

View:

```
  <div class="field">
    <label>Category</label><br />

    <select name="category[id]" id="category_id">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Controller:

```
   s = params[category_id]
   @users = User.where("status = ?", s)
```

Comment: Have a look at jQuery's [**ajax**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), [**load**](http://api.jquery.com/load/), [**get**](http://api.jquery.com/get/) or [**post**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) methods and see if any of those could help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're properly submitting the form data via GET or POST, you need to make the following change to your code

```
s = params[:category][:id] # <-- category[id] as a form field name is referenced like this through params
@users = User.where("status = ?", s)
```